# angular star rating directive with no star filled

Tags: angularjs, rating

How do I modify the angular star rating directive to display no star filled (by default) on load?
Following is the directive for the same:

```
responseController.directive('starRating', function(){

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template:
        '<ul class="star-rating" ng-class="{readonly: readonly}">' +
        '  <li ng-repeat="star in stars" class="star" ng-class="{filled: star.filled}" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
        '    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>' +
        '  </li>' +
        '</ul>',
      scope: {
        ratingValue: '=ngModel',
        max: '=?',
        onRatingSelect: '&?',
        readonly: '=?'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        if (scope.max == undefined) {
          scope.max = 5;
        }
        function updateStars() {
          scope.stars = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
            scope.stars.push({
              filled: i < scope.ratingValue
            });
          }
        };
        scope.toggle = function(index) {
          if (scope.readonly == undefined || scope.readonly === false) {
            scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
          }
        };
        scope.$watch('ratingValue', function(oldValue, newValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            updateStars();
          }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: call `scope.toggle(-1)` will show empty star

Comment: I tried that, not working for me, can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `updateStars();` before `$scope.watch(...)`. It will render not filled stars. Afterwards if the value of `ratingValue` is not undefined, the watcher will update stars.

Comment: That made the stars go blank for the first time but, on clicking the first star, it does not get filled but, when you click on the second star then both of them do get filled together, can you suggest anything for that?

Comment: wrong parameters order in scope.$watch callback. First parameter should be newValue, and the second oldValue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.directive('starRating', function () {
        return {
          //This template is used to display the star UX in repeated form.
          template: '<ul class="starRating">' + '<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggleFunck($index)">' + '\u2605' + '</li>' + '</ul>',
          scope: {
            ratingValue: '= ',
            max: '=',
            onStarRating: '&'
          },

          link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //This method is used to update the rating run time.
            var updateRating = function () {
              //This is global level collection.
              scope.stars = [];
              //Loop called with the help of data-max directive input and push the stars count.
              for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
                scope.stars.push({
                  filled: i < scope.ratingValue
                });
              }
            };
            //This is used to toggle the rating stars.
            scope.toggleFunck = function (index) {
              alert(index);
              //This is used to count the default start rating and sum the number of input index.
              scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
              scope.onStarRating({
                rating: index + 1
              });
            };
            updateRating();
            //This is used to watch activity on scope, if any changes on star rating is call automatically and update the stars.
            scope.$watch('ratingValue',
              function (newV, oldV) {
                if (newV) {
                  updateRating();
                }
              }
            );
          }
        };
      }
    );
```

Comment: Can you please explain on how this answers the question? Code-only answers are considered low quality. (From review)

Comment: Vasfed, I am still new here.. where do you put the explanation.